# SQL select rows from different tables

Tags: sql

I have the following three tables with the listed columns in the SQL database.

```
Person: PersonID, FirstName, LastName ,state,city

Email: EmailID, Email, PersonID

Order: OrderID,EmailID,Order_amt, order_date
```

I want a query that selects 50 top people who have placed order >$50, are from CA or OR or WA,and placed an order minimum 5 times within the current month, sorted by order_amt

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Should work like this. I am just online with my mobile, so i haven't been able to test it.

```
 SELECT TOP 50 Person.*, orders.*
  FROM Person
 INNER JOIN Email
 ON Person.PersonID = Email.PersonID
 INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT EmailID, SUM (Order_amt) as TotalAmt
        FROM Order 
  WHERE Order_amt > 50
    AND order_date >= DATEADD(MONTG, -1, GETDATE())
   GROUP BY EmailID
    HAVING COUNT (*) >= 5 
) orders
ON orders.EmailID = Email.EmailID
 WHERE Person.State IN ('CA','OR','WA')
 ORDER BY orders.TotalAmt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Esteban's answer but I have added some sample data (and therefore reduced the count limit just as an illustration).  It was not clear whether the 50 limit was single purchase, sum of purchases for last month or lifetime, so I have given two different versions.  Also both Esteban and I assumed "current month" was rolling.  If not, then you need to change the Date restriction.
BTW this works on SQL Server.  Note that all dbs are slightly different so please in future state in your question, which db you are using. People also prefer it, if you make some attempt yourself!

```
declare @person table
(
personid int,
firstname varchar(20),
lastname varchar(20),
[state] char(2),
city varchar(20)
);
declare @email table
(
emailid int,
email varchar(30),
personid int
);
declare @order table
(
orderid int,
emailid int,
order_amt decimal,
order_date datetime
);

INSERT INTO @person VALUES(1, 'Mickey','Mouse','CA','Los Angeles');
INSERT INTO @person VALUES(2, 'Donald','Duck','CA','San Francisco');
INSERT INTO @person VALUES(3, 'Roger','Rabbit','WA','Seattle');
INSERT INTO @person VALUES(4, 'Loadsa','Money','NY','New York');

INSERT INTO @email VALUES(1, 'm.mouse@disney.com', 1);
INSERT INTO @email VALUES(2, 'd.duck@disney.com', 2);
INSERT INTO @email VALUES(3, 'r.rabbit@buenavista.com', 3);
INSERT INTO @email VALUES(4, 'v.rich@wallstreet.com', 4);

INSERT INTO @order VALUES (1, 1, 34.20, '2017-04-15');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (2, 1, 22.25, '2017-05-18');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (3, 1, 62.30, '2017-06-18');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (4, 2, 17.20, '2017-06-02');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (5, 2, 28.40, '2017-06-20');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (6, 2, 85.60, '2017-06-22');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (7, 3, 10.30, '2017-06-03');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (8, 3, 10.70, '2017-06-24');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (9, 3, 42.60, '2017-05-25');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (10, 4, 890.79, '2017-06-03');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (11, 4, 1800.22, '2017-06-24');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (12, 4, 2000.00, '2017-06-25');
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (13, 3, 20.30, '2017-06-03');

--Version 1 Lifetime 50 order_amt limit
SELECT TOP 2 Count(o.orderid) as LastMonthBuys, 
SUM(o.order_amt) AS LastMonthSum, o.emailid, p.personid 
FROM @order o INNER JOIN @email e 
ON o.emailid = e.emailid 
inner join @person p on e.personid = p.personid
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT p2.personid FROM @person p2 
 INNER JOIN @email e2 on p2.personid = e2.emailid 
 inner join @order o2 on e2.emailid = o2.emailid 
 GROUP BY p2.personid HAVING Sum(o2.order_amt) > 50 ) 
 bigbuyers on bigbuyers.personid = p.personid
 WHERE o.order_date > DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()) 
 AND p.state IN ('CA', 'WA', 'OR') 
 GROUP BY o.emailid, p.personid
 HAVING Count(o.orderid) > 2
 ORDER BY LastMonthSum DESC

--Version 2 50 order_amt limit for last month
 SELECT TOP 2 Count(o.orderid) as LastMonthBuys, 
SUM(o.order_amt) AS LastMonthSum, o.emailid, p.personid 
FROM @order o INNER JOIN @email e 
ON o.emailid = e.emailid 
inner join @person p on e.personid = p.personid
WHERE o.order_date > DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()) 
 AND p.state IN ('CA', 'WA', 'OR') 
 GROUP BY p.personid, o.emailid
 HAVING Count(o.orderid) > 2 AND SUM(o.order_amt) > 50
 ORDER BY LastMonthSum DESC
```